# brew services list shows error undefined method `chomp'

Tags: homebrew

I have a osx bigsur and installed homebrew. Why when I run `brew services list` I get error:

```
Error: undefined method `chomp' for nil:NilClass
  /opt/homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew 
  services/lib/service/services_cli.rb:53:in `user_of_process'
 /opt/homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew- 
 services/lib/service/services_cli.rb:139:in `block in list'
 /opt/homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew- 
 services/lib/service/services_cli.rb:127:in `map'
 /opt/homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew- 
 services/lib/service/services_cli.rb:127:in `list'
 /opt/homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew- 
 services/lib/service/commands/list.rb:9:in `run'
 /opt/homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-services/cmd/services.rb:84:in `services'
 /opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:129:in `<main>'
```

When I run `sudo brew services list`, then all working good. How I can resolve issue with command without sudo ? `brew services list`

Comment: What is your output for `brew config` and `brew doctor`?

Comment: @FnControlOption https://imgur.com/3EgbYNX - brew config, but brew doctor shows: Your system is ready to brew.